# Run node module in guest executable

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I've got a global npm package installed, [TileServer](https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-gl), that I run as service through command line.  I'd like to convert this to a guest executable in service fabric, but I'm having trouble implementing.

Pre-Guest executable, I would invoke the following command in cmd:

```
tileserver-gl-light --port=8788 map.mbtiles
```

My configuration for my guest executable is:

```
<ExeHost>
  <Program>tileserver-gl-light</Program>
  <Arguments>--port=8788 c:\maptiles.mbtiles</Arguments>
  <WorkingFolder>Work</WorkingFolder>
</ExeHost>
```

Unfortunately, the error I get when trying to run the service just says "*There were deployment errors. Continue?*"

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Thanks!

Comment: This link might help: https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/776

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check to see if that application package validates on your local machine by calling Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage?

Usually SF expects the  file to be

1. Present in the application package and
2. Some sort of executable file that the OS understands (for windows .bat, .exe, etc.)

In this case I think what you're saying is that the tileserver bits are actually outside the package (wherever your node packages are), and you're actually trying to use **node** to start it (since the tileserver-gl packages aren't natively executable by Windows).

If that's the case your program should probably be something like a batch file that just says "tileserver-gl-light" and then your command line args in it.

Include that batch file in your code package and reference that as your program (and straighten out how you want to pass the args) and you should be good to go.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction, particularly #2 above.  So, I've marked this as the accepted answer.  I'll provide a mode detailed answer below as there were some nuances for this particular case.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 2):

As @masnider pointed out, the files must be present in the application package, and we must call the executable as something the OS understands.  This presents particular challenges for node modules as:

1. They must be wrapped in a .bat
2. They can't be called using the global command
3. They need parameters
4. They files, node_modules, often has issues with file path length issues

My end service had the following file structure:

```
- ApplicationPackageRoot
  - MyService.ServicePkg
   - Code
     - 7za.exe
     - node.exe
     - npm.7z
     - start.bat
```

My ServiceManifest.xml had these values in it:

```
<SetupEntryPoint>
  <ExeHost>
    <Program>7za.exe</Program>
    <Arguments>x npm.7z<Arguments>
    <WorkingFolder>CodeBase</WorkingFolder>
  </ExeHost>
</SetupEntryPoint>

<EntryPoint>
  <ExeHost>
    <Program>start.bat</Program>
    <Arguments><Arguments>
    <WorkingFolder>CodeBase</WorkingFolder>
  </ExeHost>

  <EnvironmentVariables>
    <EnvironmentVariable Name="Port" Value="8788"/>
    <EnvironmentVariable Name="TilePath" Value="mytiles.mbtiles"/>
  </EnvironmentVariables>
</EntryPoint>
```

And finally, my `start.bat` was comprised of the following line:

```
.\node.exe npm/node_modules/tileserver-gl-light/sc/main.js --port=%Port% %TilePath%
```

So how did this work?  The npm.7z in the Code consisted of my node_modules, pre-zipped.  The 7za was the portable version of 7zip which allows use to get around the file path length issues present on windows.  7za is called in the SetupEntryPoint.

Then the SF calls start.bat, which reads in the environmental variables of Port and TilePath.  This has to called the exactly .js file called by the normal tileserver-gl-light command.

Doing this results in a properly working node application in a service fabric guest executable.